# TypeScript: Inferring the correct type for a function that evaluates function properties on a generic object

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-inference, typescript-generics

I want to define a function that works like so:

```
const result = evaluate({x: () => 2 * 3, y: () => "hello"})
```

Where the value of `result` is:

```
{x: 6, y: "hello"}
```

To the best of my knowledge, the definition has to look something like:

```
function evaluate<T>(obj: Record<keyof T, () => T[keyof T]>): T {
    // Copy the key-value pairs, invoking each value.
    // There are a few different ways to do this.
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries<() => T[keyof T]>(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v()})))
}
```

However, this doesn't quite work. On the example provided earlier, the type of `result` is inferred as:

```
{x: unknown, y: unknown}
```

The function call **does** work as expected if the type parameter is provided explicitly:

```
const result = evaluate<{x: number, y: string}>({x: () => 2 * 3, y: () => "hello"})
```

Is there some way I can get type inference to work correctly?

Comment: The related issue seems to be [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/19227), why you can't infer the object literal from a `keyof` function parameter type properly. I think, instead of the property value type being `{}`, they changed it to `unknown` as common super type at some point in time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think TS is smart enough to resolve `T` in this way.

The solution is simple, you can capture in `T` the type of the parameter and use a custom mapped type to get transform the parameter to the type you want:

```
const result = evaluate({x: () => 2 * 3, y: () => "hello"})

function evaluate<T extends Record<keyof T, () => any>>(obj: T): {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
} {
    // Copy the key-value pairs, invoking each value.
    // There are a few different ways to do this.
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries<() => T[keyof T]>(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v()})))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgVwDawLwwQNwIarJ5QIAUA3gB4BcMpAlDBgHwwBMMAVDAMwA0MAJ60GTVgCIAFglSoQ4gL70AsACg1AM2RhgUAJbhs+QsQQAeACrZKJMABMIMAEoJQcO2YDWCQSA0wLAVEWGDwwQWZmUhAAIwArWgt6WnI1GHSYAG0ABRg9MBhvX38LAF1aFyhkODALQQAHcwsc0uY1BRhU1QyYAHpemABhEHrBGChpQp8AWmNkBBh6vD04CAF8nBBPfIBzbDxgSRg5hAA6NIz+gOlEUNu8GA0EAHcYOz0NJ8QwWGe8QUcUBAb2BEz0EHO3QyiCqNRgAHl4q4oKc8BAIHodmAKAoBKd8Yi4sjTggfnA9EgzMFWM0in4Aq1ovF6KcALZ4eqkUiZTwCHClRghCg88rHBhKegqVQKIA)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about ReturnType. Thank you! This was driving me crazy.